# The best way to pass a null List to a Stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a scenario where in I have to pass two parameters. One is a BigInteger and another is a list of BigIntegers. The first parameter cannot be null but the second parameter which is a list can be coming as a null list from the request. The stored procedure will take care of rest of the things how to get the result even though second parameter is null. How can I handle this in java code in a decent way? Can I pass in the null list as it is?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure, you can mark the second parameter as Optional. When your second list is null, you can call the procedure with just one parameter from java.